# How to block any script from affecting an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a problem that i am working on a pre-developed script and adding my custom input fields, and every thing is fine except that an input which contains default value doesn't show the value while it is set in value attribute,

```
<input id="complete_within" type="text" value="5" class="mr-text">
```

The value 5 is not showing and i think there is a script that cleans it for some reason.

**Why do i think so?**

Because the value displays if i called this field through AJAX, but once i add it directly to page, it doesn't.

Is there any way to stop any event applied for specific element or to know which script is doing this?

Comment: In google chrome you can put a DOM breakpoint on the element and then inspect the stack trace to see which script is acting on it.

Comment: Also disable javaScript to make sure if javaScript is the source of problem.

Comment: But why can’t you edit the pre-developed script?  You can’t “protect” a DOM element fron a running script.

Comment: just find the script that is effecting the element and ignore/comment that one, otherwise you can't achieve what you are saying.
Note: In worst case you could  create a node same as that input element with add/remove whenever you want.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Thank you, i took your advice and i have make sure it is